# what is a new way for remote desktop

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, vnc

i want to connect t my server without using remote desktop of windows or VNC . 
can you help me with another way and explain for me a new way for remote desktop? 
my server is : windows 2003

Comment: Only if you can explain why Remote Desktop and VNC won't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Citrix XenApp, if you're rich.

Or I guess you could set up a webcam and use something like Synergy to send mouse and keyboard commands.  (No, that was not a serious suggestion.)

Answer (score 0):

what about telnet? Of course you need to use a command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Use Remote Desktop. It works well, integrates with user accounts, etc. etc. I don't see why you wouldn't want this?

If you want to log in to it from a Linux box, [NX Client](http://www.nomachine.com/screenshots.php) works quite well and is free.

Answer (score 0):

ThinVNC is a pure web alternative that uses HTML5 to replace the old VNC.

Here you have a link to the product page. There's a exe setup ready to be used, and ThinVNC is free for non commercial use:

[ThinVNC](http://www.supportsmith.com/ThinVNC/HTML5-VNC.aspx)

:)